# Most efficient way of turning an array of UInt8Array into an ArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, buffer, grpc

I am streaming a file from a gRPC backend to my javascript client. The stream sends a series of UInt8Array objects. I want to combine this series of UInt8Array into one single arrayBuffer (i.e. the original file's arrayBuffer). How can I do this?